# ExtJS Controller trigger on hyperlink click

Tags: extjs, controller, extjs4

I've been trying to get this to work for quite a while now but I still haven't been able to find a solution for this except adding a afterrender inside listeners in the view. But I want the controller to handle it.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this?

This is what I have in my files at the moment
http://pastie.org/2751446

```
controller/App.js

    Ext.define('HD.controller.App', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'
     ,views: [
         'core.Header',
         'core.Navigation',
         'core.Content'
     ]
     ,init: function() {
         this.control({
             'navigation a[id=tab1]': {
                 click: this.newTab
             }
         })
     }
     ,newTab: function() {
         console.log('Tab 1 should be loaded now');
     }
});
```

view/core/Navigation.js

```
Ext.define('HD.view.core.Navigation', {
     extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel'
    ,name: 'navigation'
    ,alias: 'widget.navigation'
    ,layout: 'accordion'
    ,region: 'west'
    ,width: 200

    ,title: 'Navigation'
    ,collapsible: true

    ,items: [
        {
            title: 'Title 1'
            ,html: '<a id="tab1" style="cursor:pointer;">Tab 1</a>'
        },
        {
            title: 'Title 2'
            ,html: 'Second'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are trying to reference the hyperlink `a` won't work.

```
this.control({
   'navigation a[id=tab1]': {
      click: this.newTab
   }
})
```

That will only look for ExtJS components, not DOM elements.  You will most likely have to attach the click in afterrender or somewhere similar.  This does not mean you can't leave the methods that do all the work in the controller.

Edit:

```
var controller = this;
controller.control({
   'navigation': {
      afterrender: function() {
           Ext.get('tab1').on('click', function() {
                controller.newTab();
           });
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply s_hewitt. I will try spinning this into something that works when I get home from work :)

Comment: I've been trying to solve this. If I replace the comment in the view's afterrender with an alert, it's triggered properly. But it's the link between the view and controller that I'm struggling with. Also I'm not sure if I've done it right regarding the "newTab" part in my controller. Here is my current code: http://pastie.org/2757329

Comment: Move the `afterrender` listener to your controller.  See my edit.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm :) Do you mind explaining why this.control doesn't work but when making it a variable it works?

Comment: It will work either way.  But it needs to be setup as a variable so you can access it from within the `click` function - using `this` in the on click function will refer to the Ext object representing 'tab1'.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that when trying to make the tab and not just alert a "success message". I have actually started building my first real app :) again, thanks for helping me out with this. Both accepted and voted up your answer

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with issue as well. The bottom line is the Controller control config does not work like the regular listeners and will only act on the events which are fired by the component and not by DOM as s_hewitt pointed out.

The alternatives are somewhat ugly with essentially listeners on the components or parent components where you can use delegates as well. Once you go that route it's not as clean cut as setting up listeners in the controller.

Another trick I used to get around this limitation is calling controller methods from the view components like this:

```
MyApp.app.getController('MyController').myFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs DmitryB. But by modifying s_hewitt's answer a tiny bit my app now works soly on all views controlled only by its controller, but I will note this in case I need to do an approach like this :)